# Can SCOM be used to monitor physical servers as well as virtual?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, scom

Doing some research for a proposal and need to know if the Microsoft SCOM product is capable of monitoring physical servers.  I have already seen it used in a VM environment with AWS, but need to know if it has the same capabilities when monitoring physical, non-virtualized servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can.  There are also a lot of neat hardware vendor-specific packages for it.

Comment: Figured as much, but didn't specifically see anything on the System Center website about it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: As a general rule, unless your software specifically operates on the hypervisor, virtual machines are functionally identical to real ones.